# Match digits in a URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to be able to extract a group of digits between a url that doesn't use the lookbehind (?<=) as I just realized it isn't support in all browsers.

url:
https://example.com/img/33421/contact_1739081.jpeg?mod=12741-1385

I want to extract the '1739081' between the contact_ and .jpeg

originally I used the following regex: (?<=contact_)(.*)(?=.jpeg)
which worked but as stated above isn't supported by all browsers.

is there any other regex methods to use in order to extract the group  of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try regex

```js
let URL = 'https://example.com/img/33421/contact_1739081.jpeg?mod=12741-1385';
let getMatch = URL.match(/contact_(\d+)/);
if (getMatch) {
    let contact = getMatch[1];
    console.log(contact);
}else{
  console.log('No Match');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution could be to just run two matches. The first captures the group between "contact" and ".jpeg" and the second captures only the numbers inside this match.

```
const url = "https://example.com/img/33421/contact_1739081.jpeg?mod=12741-1385";

function findContactNumber(url) {
  const outerMatch = url.match(/contact_\d+\.jpeg/);
  if (!outerMatch) return null;
  const innerMatch = outerMatch[0].match(/\d+/);
  if (!innerMatch) return null;
  return innerMatch[0];
}
```